# WSO2 Developer Studio 2.1.0 (previously Carbon Studio) plug-in causes Eclipse load to hang

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am trying to install the new WSO2 Developer Studio 2.1.0 into Eclipse. It appeared to install successfully, but when I try to start Eclipse it hangs forever (e.g. > 30 minutes) with the message “Loading Workbench”. On one attempt (after leaving it for maybe 45 minutes), it actually got as far as bringing up the Eclipse main window, but it hung there with the message “Marketplace DND Initialization”. The Eclipse process is steadily using about 25% of my CPU.

There is an error in my Eclipse workspace/.metadata/.log file:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 4 0 2012-10-17 11:20:18.303
!MESSAGE An extension already exists with id "org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent".
This appears about 20 times per attempt to load Eclipse, all in the first few seconds after initiating the load.

I followed the WSO2 Developer Studio installation guide (http://dist.wso2.org/products/developer-studio/2.1.0/docs/install_guide.html). I was unclear about the prerequisites. It says “Eclipse WTP 3.1.0 or higher”, but that appears to be from old Eclipse versions (Galileo), so I didn’t worry about it. My Eclipse About screen says WTP 1.0. The other prerequisite was for Carbon Server. I am already running latest BPS server (beta), which includes Carbon, so I didn’t worry about it. Just to be sure, I later installed the latest stand-alone “Carbon Server”, but that didn’t help any.

I also tried increasing memory settings in eclipse.ini by 50% (to XXMaxPermSize: 384, -Xmx768m) from the default. No help.

Here is my system:
MS-Windows 7 Enterprise on a 64-bit laptop
Java 1.6
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, Indigo 3.7, 32-bit. Version 1.4.0.20110615-0550
(relevant) Eclipse features:
WTP Version: 1.0.0.v201104180000-797B1CcNBHGC_DRAwXT3B
Subclipse 1.6.x
Aptana Studio 3.0.4 MS Windows x86 “Eclipse plug-in version”. Version: 3.0.4.201108101432-7E37B7HFEHCdSHSV5R_IyJetqA_B
CollabNet Merge Client 2.2.4

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just downloaded Eclipse Helios Sr2 version of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, it seems to work OK, I'm able to install Developer Studio and load Eclipse. I guess I'll just run 2 versions of Eclipse for now...

Answer (score 4):

Hi I faced the same problem especially with nested WSO2 projects / multi module Maven projects. A little change on my Eclipse Project Explorer Settings solved the problem for me.

What I have done:

1. Open View Customization menu on Eclipse Project Exlporer (the triangle in menu bar of the view)
2. Clicked "Customize View..."
3. Unchecked "Hide WSO2 Registry Resource Conflict Items" and "Hide nested projects"
4. Apply by clicking "OK"

As a result all nested folders will be shown in a flat layout (as usual from m2e-Integration for multimodule Maven projects) but the IDE is now faster and less cpu consuming and doesn't freeze on save anymore.

My Environement looks like:

- OS: Windows 7 64bit
- Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 (Build: 20120216-1857)
- Eclipse WTP 3.40
- Java JDK 1.6.0_31 (32-bit)
- WSO2 Developer Studio 2.1.0
- M2E-Integration 1.2.0.20120903-1050
- M2E-WTP  0.17.0.20121108-1856

Hope it helps

**Edit:** Sorry I forgot to mention that I had to go through the steps from Harshana first after a fresh installation of WSO2 Developer Studio 2.1.0. My JVM is parameterized with -Xms512m
-Xmx1384m.

Comment: Maryan, Andy, Thanks for reporting this and providing a nice workaround. We also later figured that out that, there was a serious performance problem associated with Nested Project Structure and related indexing and searching. I'm glad to inform you that we have addressed this performance problem in Developer Studio 3.0.0 version and we are no longer experiencing that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to clean your System Temp folder before starting the Eclipse instance and see whether there is an improvement?

And please use a fresh Eclipse workspace after installing Developer Studio.

We have seen this behavior couple of times in the past and above 2 procedures and increased memory helped to resolve the issue.

Hope this helps!

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Answer (score 0):

Developer studio 3.5 beta 2 is released. It improved with lot of bug fixes.
http://devamanthrils.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/developer-studio-3-5-0-beta-2-released/